# The proof that $L_{2}[a,b]$ is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The proof is given in these pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Starting from the paragraph saying "for each $x$,  is an increasing sequence...... " till the end, I do not understand what is the author doing, could anyone please divide the proof for me into steps?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the given proof is already pretty elaborate, so I don't know if it would be very helpful if I just wrote a slightly longer proof. It is probably more efficient if you would point out the exact points in the proof you do not understand, so we can explain.

Comment: @Demophilus   I need to understand the general steps in the proof, not detailed one. like in the proof that $l_{2}$ is complete Kreyszig divided it into 3 steps 1- defining x, 2- proving that $x \in l_{2}$ , 3- proving that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$.

Comment: Completeness of any normed linear space is equivalent to showing that every absolutely summable series of vectors converges as a vector series. (Apparently that's the previous proposition before this theorem.)1. Author starts with such a series. 2. Author shows that the sum of the functions converges pointwise a.e. to a finite limit $s$, which he also shows is in $L^p$. 3. After that, everything reduces to showing that the sequence of partial sums converges to $s$ in $L^p$ norm.